# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setText:]

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am making an app and using tableview controller in it and using checkboxes in table view cell. all are working fine but when i scroll down tableview it is working fine but when i scroll up tableview then it is giving an exception mentioned above.below is my sample code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [checkimageArray removeAllObjects];
    [lblArray removeAllObjects];
    self.MainView.hidden=YES;




    checkBoxesCount=0;
    self.lblArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    self.image.hidden=YES;
    self.checkimageArray=[NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) // when i decrease this loop to 12 it waz working fine but on 15 it is not working
    {
        [self.lblArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell Number %d",i]];
    }
    [self.activitiesTableView_ reloadData];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return self.lblArray.count;
}
```

and this is me setting cell method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){
        // [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Load more records"];
    }

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:13];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:14];
    [valuedate setText:@"Demo"];
    [msg  setText:@"How are You?"];
    date.text=@"14/07/2014";
    time.text=@"A 08:16";
    cell.image.layer.borderColor=(__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor blackColor]);
    cell.image.layer.borderWidth=2.0;



    valuedate.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:15];
    msg.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:10.0];
    date.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:9];
    time.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:9];
    [cell.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];






    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"]
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }

    cell.button.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    return cell;

   }
```

Comment: Hey Mishal, From crash log, It seems like you are giving direct text to your UIButton Object

Comment: means ??? i am unable to get u

Comment: Can you please suggest me at which exact line your code does crash? Then it will little bit easy to give guidance you.

Comment: see my updated question when i decrease loop to 12 it is working fine but whenever i increase this loop it it is showing an exception

Comment: If you have given Table Datsource and Delegate then why "[self.activitiesTableView_ reloadData];" in ViewDidLoad ??

Comment: iif i erase it then still same issue

Comment: It is Just regarding to Imrove code statics, See answer of "Lyndsey Scott", I think it's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `cell.button.tag` to `indexPath.row` and if there are 12 or more rows, your `UIButtons`s can end up having the the same tag as one of your `UILabel`s already tagged 11 - 14. So what's occasionally happening when you call `[cell viewWithTag:11];` for example, is that you're pulling out the `UIButton` and not the `UILabel` (the cast doesn't change that) and so you end up attempting to set the `UIButton` text when that property doesn't exist -- thus the `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setText:]` error. I suggest setting your `UILabel` tags to contain numbers far beyond your row count so there's no conflict.